# Algebraic equivalence of cycles and Chow varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $p,d\geq 0$ be two integers and let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^N$ be a complex projective variety. Denote the Chow variety of $X$ consisting of $p$-cycles of degree $d$ by $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$. I'm trying to check that two cycles $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{\prime}$ in $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$ are algebraically equivalent (as defined at pag. 10 of [this](https://jfresan.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/lectures-murre.pdf)) if they lie in the same path connected component of $\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$.

It seems, by taking a look at this [paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1991__77_1_55_0.pdf) (proof of Prop. 1.8) that the strategy is to prove that there is a bijective correspondence between morphisms $C\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}_{p,d}(X)$ ($C$ is a smooth curve) and $\mathcal{C}_{p+1,r}(C\times X)$.

I'm looking for a proof of the fact above which avoids any use of scheme theory.

Any help is well accepted.

Comment: Why are you attempting to avoid scheme theory in this question? What sorts of substitutes are you (potentially) looking for?

Comment: To say the truth I'm trying to avoid scheme theory because I know only few things about scheme theory, therefore I'm not able to completelly  underdtand  Friedlander's paper.

Comment: How did you come to be learning about Chow varieties without knowing much scheme theory? Whatever the answer, I would recommend picking up the necessary material here. None of the things leading up to the proof of 1.8 should be so bad (seems to be mainly some basic applications of flatness and some relatively elementary geometric reasoning).

Comment: You can learn about chow varieties of projective varieties without any scheme theory, see, for instance, this book : Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants. Anyway, I think that I will follow your advice.